# I am Unable to retrieve data from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am posting this question because I haven't found any proper solution related to my problem.

I am trying to retrieve my sensor data from Firebase but I am unable to do it. Please point out where am I doing wrong

Try.java

```
public class Try extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;

ListView list;
DatabaseReference databaseTry;

List<TryObjectClass> tryObjectList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_try);

    databaseTry = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("sensor_data");

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    tryObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseTry.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            tryObjectList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot TrySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                TryObjectClass tryObjectClass = 
TrySnapshot.getValue(TryObjectClass.class);

                tryObjectList.add(tryObjectClass);
            }

            TryAdapter adapter = new TryAdapter(Try.this, tryObjectList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
}
```

This is my object class

TryObjectClass.java

```
public class TryObjectClass  {

private String date;
private String time;
private String humidity;
private String motion;
private String distance;
private String temperature;



public TryObjectClass(){

}

public TryObjectClass(String date, String time, String humidity, String 
motion, String distance, String temperature) {
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.humidity = humidity;
    this.motion = motion;
    this.distance = distance;
    this.temperature = temperature;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getHumidity() {
    return humidity;
}

public void setHumidity(String humidity) {
    this.humidity = humidity;
}

public String getMotion() {
    return motion;
}

public void setMotion(String motion) {
    this.motion = motion;
}

public String getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(String distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public String getTemperature() {
    return temperature;
}

public void setTemperature(String temperature) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
}
}
```

This is my adapter class

TryAdapter.java

```
public class TryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TryObjectClass> {

private Activity context;
private List<TryObjectClass> objectList;

public TryAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, List<TryObjectClass> 
objectList) {
    super(context, R.layout.new_list,0);
    this.context = context;
    this.objectList = objectList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list,null,true);

    TextView date = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView distance = (TextView) 
listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    TextView humidity = (TextView) 
listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.humidity);
    TextView motion = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.motion);
    TextView temperature = (TextView) 
listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.temperature);
    TextView time = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.time);

    TryObjectClass tryObjectClass = objectList.get(position);

    date.setText(tryObjectClass.getDate());
    distance.setText(tryObjectClass.getDistance());
    humidity.setText(tryObjectClass.getHumidity());
    motion.setText(tryObjectClass.getMotion());
    temperature.setText(tryObjectClass.getTemperature());
    time.setText(tryObjectClass.getTime());

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
}
```

try_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Try"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Retrieved data"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click here to retrieve the data"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my list item

new_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date -"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Distance -"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Humidity -"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/humidity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Motion -"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/motion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Temperature -"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time -"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my database

```
smartborder-cef61
sensor_data
    100
        date: 1875
        distance: "50M"
        humidity:  4573
        motion: "yes"
        temperature: "30c"
        time: 7377200
    200
        date: 23111996
        distance: "50M"
        humidity: 45
        motion: "yes"
        temperature: "30C"
        time: 73775
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Do you have an error?

Comment: Can you please specify what problem you are facing and where?

Comment: I am unable to populate the listview

Comment: The list view remains empty when the app is started

Comment: First learn to debug your code. Try to print the data from firebase into your log, and confirm you are getting values. If you are getting them, check wether it is adding to the list by printing the list in your log. If all of them is working then check for list view code. you can print data into log by using `Log.e("key", "your data");`. Figure out where the problem is ocurring.

Comment: Thanks I&#39;ll try it out @Jerin A Mathews

Comment: bro i am getting the values in logcat but it is not showing it in my listview

Answer (score 0):

I found something, try to put your `setAdapter()` **outside** your listener.
**Inside** your listener you will put this code:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot TrySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                TryObjectClass tryObjectClass = TrySnapshot.getValue(TryObjectClass.class);
                tryObjectList.add(tryObjectClass);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And try to put your declared things in `onCreate` method, like your ValueEventListener, so you can add it in `onStart` and remove it in `onDestroy` when your activity have not to listen your changes anymore when your activity is destroyed. Here's part of my fragment ContatsFragment, it is working fine:

```
public class ContatsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Contat> contats;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private ValueEventListener valueEventListenerContatos;
    private Context context;

    public ContatsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        context = getActivity();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListenerContatos);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListenerContatos);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        contats = new ArrayList<>();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contats, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_contatos);

        adapter = new ContatAdapter(getActivity(), contats);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Preferences preferences = new Preferences(getActivity());
        String loggedUserId = preferences.getLoggedUserId();

        databaseReference = FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseReference();
        databaseReference = databaseReference.child("contats")
                .child(loggedUserId);

        valueEventListenerContatos = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                contats.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dados : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Contat contat = dados.getValue(Contat.class);
                    contats.add(contat);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution...I made mistake in the giving the list object name...